# OpenLDAP , make test, How can I know it has been successful

Tags: openldap

I am new-ish to OpenLDAP and performing a "make test"

It throws a lot of output.

Is there a way to know whether it was successful in a agile manner?

I did this: "make test > file1.txt"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you compiling OpenLDAP? Is the distro repo version somehow deficient?

Comment: I have to, nothing to do with deficiencies, has to do with client's requirement.